# Spark Datagrid editor - numbers only

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, editor, flex4, flex-spark

I want a spark datagrid that allow a user to input numbers only. They can only input number with up to 5 decimal places. I am struggling with this in Spark. I can do it in Flex by using the itemEditEnd parameter of the MX DataGrid.

How do I do this is Spark? Any pointers would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [itemEditor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#itemEditor) that is a custom [TextInput](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextInput.html) that uses the [restrict](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html#restrict) property to limit the characters entered in editable phase.

This is probably the same way I would have done it with the MX DataGrid, I'm not sure what you did in itemEditEnd.  If you want to validate the input the user entered outside of the actual itemEditor component, probably [gridItemEditorSessionSave](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#event%3agridItemEditorSessionSave) is the closest analogy to itemEditEnd.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the previous answer: for simplicity you can extend the default grid item editor and override its 'restrict' property.

```
import spark.components.gridClasses.DefaultGridItemEditor;

public class GridItemEditorNumber extends DefaultGridItemEditor {

  public function GridItemEditorNumber() {
    super();
    textArea.restrict = "0-9\\.";
  }

}
```

or, if you prefer to use an inline declaration in the GridColumn:

```
<s:itemEditor>
  <fx:Component>
    <s:DefaultGridItemEditor initialize="textArea.restrict='0-9\.'"/>
  </fx:Component>
</s:itemEditor>
```

Comment: I get an error that you can not call initialize in your inline example

Comment: That's right. There was an error. It is fixed now. Thank you for flagging.